# Trouble with audio tag, jQuery, and currentTime

Tags: jquery, html

```
<audio src="file.ogg" type="audio/ogg" controls="controls"></audio>​
```

Why is it that this jQuery/JavaScript works:

```
var audio = $('audio').get(0);
audio.play();
```

But this doesn't?:

```
var audio = $('audio').get(0);
audio.currentTime = 20;
audio.play();
```

[​jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H5EJh/)

Comment: If you set the currentTime its taking a delay to buffer and so the play is working after sometime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var audio = $('audio');
audio.bind('canplay', function() {
        this.currentTime = 20;
});
audio.get(0).play();
```