# HTML5 currentTime not working in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap and making an app for Samsung Galaxy Tab 2. I'm trying to play a mp4 video starting at a specific time. Using this code the video only starts from the beginning, and not 20 seconds in. What could be wrong?

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var playerDiv = document.getElementById('player');

    playerDiv.innerHTML="<video id='video' src='"+window.localStorage.getItem("selectedVideo")+"' loop='loop' width='1285' height='752'></video>";

    document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
        this.currentTime = 20;
    }, false);
}

function playVideo() {
    document.getElementById('video').play();
}
```

I have also tried this, but it still starts from the beginning:

```
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
   this.currentTime = 20;
   this.play();
}, false);
```

And using canplay insted of loadedmetedata does not work.

Comment: Could you specify your Android version?

Comment: I'm using Android 4.0.4

Answer (score 2):

here is similar question

[Trouble with audio tag, jQuery, and currentTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064449/trouble-with-audio-tag-jquery-and-currenttime)

```
var audio = $('audio');
audio.bind('canplay', function() {
        this.currentTime = 20;
});
audio.get(0).play();
```